# Is there a way to set db connection settings for all connection under same function in laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Let say I have the following database settings in app/config/database.php

```
'default' => 'mysql',

'connections' => array(

    # Our primary database connection
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host1',
        'database'  => 'database1',
        'username'  => 'user1',
        'password'  => 'pass1'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    # Our secondary database connection
    'mysql2' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host2',
        'database'  => 'database2',
        'username'  => 'user2',
        'password'  => 'pass2'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
),
```

From the official guide of laravel, there are a few ways to choose which connection settings to use. Either set it when I need to make the connection,

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);
```

or set it in the model:

```
class SomeModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $connection = 'mysql2';

}
```

In my case, I have duplicated databases with same schema for different users, so it is impossible to set it in the model. Is there a way to choose connection settings for all connection under the same function so that I can put it in the filter / baseController and set the connection on the run?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to update the 'database.default' key and reconnect:

```
Config::set('database.default', 'mysql2');
DB::reconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a third solution (the last one): http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

So you can pass the connection name into the function or set it in the controller.

Comment: The last solution only changed the settings for connection under that modal. If I make connection of different model, I still need to set again. This is better than setting every time, but I want a once and for all solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default connection to 'mysql2' just by doing this.

```
DB::setDefaultConnection('mysql2');
```